# Android сервис останавливается, когда activity закрывается (API26+), хотя я использую startForegroundService() и startForeground() in Service

Tags: android, android-service

При нажатии на кнопку onStart() запускается сервис в фоне и должен работать, даже, когда приложение закрыто. Код MainActivity:

```
    public void onStart(View view){
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
    startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, startIntent);
    } else {
        startService(startIntent);
    }
}
```

Код в Service:

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    startMyNotification();
    return START_STICKY
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int 
    startId) {       
    if(intent.getAction()
    .equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION))
   {
   startMyNotification();
   }

  private void startMyNotification(){
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        NotificationChannel channel = new 
  NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Channel title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) 
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    Notification notification = new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Text").build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
   }
  }
 }
```

В чем может быть проблема? Уже много перепробовала вариантов, которые могли бы исправить эту проблему, но ничего не помогает..

Comment: В манифесте нужно тоже прописывать сервис.